# Making a tree of n children to store directories of computer

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I am making a tree of n children to store directories of computer. Now, concept is simply make a tree (that would not be a BT of course) and each node will have children as well. Consider the code below then I will explain the problem.
First Consider this:

```
C/users/DeadCoder/Movies/Batman.
```

Now In my `main.cpp` I have this all C, users, DeadCoder, Movies, Batman in a vector and then I send two pairs in insert Func. if `root==NULL`; it would just insert C. Next time C and users would go. It would find C and then insert users occordingly. Let's now see the code .

```
template <class T>

struct Node;

template <class T>
class tree
{
    Node<T> *root;

public:

    tree();
    ~tree();
    int insert(T str, T str1);
    Node<T> *getRoot();
    Node<T> *search(T item, Node<T> *tempPtr);
};

template <class T>
struct Node{

    T n;
    Node<T> *sibling;
    tree<T> children; // SEE my each node has children.
    Node(T N){
        this->n = N;
        this->sibling = NULL;
    }

};
```

// In .cpp FILE;
// Initilaizer

```
template <class T>
tree<T>::tree() // Constructor Initialization.
{
    root=NULL;
}
```

// Insert Function.

```
template <class T>
int tree<T>::insert(T push, T find)
{

    Node<T> *rPtr = root;
    if (rPtr==NULL){
            //ROOT is NULL. C needs to be inserted which is in find.
        Node<T> *pusPtr = new Node<T>(find);              

        root = pushPtr;
        root->sibling=NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(rPtr!=NULL){
        Node<T> *pushPtr = new Node<T>(push);
        Node<T> *temp2 =  search(find, root);   
        Node<T> *temp = temp2->children.getRoot(); // say it LINE_40.
        if (temp==NULL){ 
            temp = pushPtr;
            temp->sibling=NULL;
            return 1;

        }
        // children are already present.
        else if(temp!=NULL){

            // You don't need to know code for this part.
            }
    }//if.
```

}

// Search Function.

```
template <class T>
Node<T> *tree<T>::search(T data, treeNode<T>* N)
{
    if (N->n==data){ // where n represent directory.
        return N; // data found. 
    }//if....
    else{

        Node<T> *child = N->children.getRoot(); 
// This is where i get Segmentation fault,
// because child is ==NULL; but you see in LINE_40 I did insert the child for C.


    if(child!=NULL){ // say it line 80.
        search(data, child);
    }//if...
    if(child->sibling!=NULL){
        search(data, child->sibling);
    }   
   }


}// search....
```

PROBLEM: `C` inserted. `Users` inserted. Now in search function at Line 80, it comes to find the child for C. and it should be Users as I have inserted it in LINE 40. BUT Instead it says child==NULL. I have been debugging for hours and I don't know why it says so. I hope Everybody gets the problem.
Now I really need to know why it is regarding C child to be NULL, It has to be users. Can anyOne see what is the problem???? HELP !!!!

Comment: Still Waiting for someone to respond...........!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Line 42 does *nothing* (I mean it has no side effect). It just puts a value in a temporary variable then leaves.
You probably want your `temp` to be a reference to the root. Something like: `Node<T> *&temp =`

Comment: How to make it reference to root. I thought the same that it might not be working. Can you post the code. I am just a learner. Don't Understand much of what you said

Comment: in fact, there are so many things to clarify in your code that it will be hard to give you directions. For example, your "insert": if you expect it to act elsewhere than on children, you should give it a path not just a single element. Also your methods have very generic names and parameters such as "str", "str1". This is against any naming logic what are their purpose? without clear naming, nobody will be able to really help. That's why also you have such a hard time with your code, you cannot understand yourself when re-reading what it really does. So, clarify your code and your bugs will go

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `insert` method actually inserted these elements?
It might be helpful to implement postconditions so to verify your methods actually fulfill their contract (*design by contract*).
This way you'll directly get what is wrong and debugging will be fast or unnecessary in some cases,  since you'll get log messages saying "this method was supposed to do this but failed doing it", otherwise you'll look for hours where the problems comes from.